# Вывод из БД, группировка содержимого

Tags: php, mysql

Решил сделать для сайта систему личных сообщений. Есть страница с кратким содержанием сообщения, ссылка имеет вид mysite.ru/message, и есть страница с полным содержанием mysite.ru/message?id=1. Нужно сделать так, чтобы у каждого пользователя были сообщения с одинаковыми id, в смысле что у каждого есть сообщения с id 1,2,3,4,5...и т.д., чтобы путем простой подстановки цифры в id нельзя было посмотреть чужое сообщение. Только как это реализовать не пойму? Если к таблице с сообщениями добавить поле id с автоинкрементом, то у пользователя который зарегистрируется к примеру через год, ссылка на первое сообщение будет примерно такая mysite.ru/message?id=32571. Если не понятно объяснил, такая же система используется в соц сетях, например Вк.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замечательно, **вариант первый**, давайте назовем это системой диалогов, и попробуем ее сделать так:

Есть таблица пользователей, каждый кортеж хранит как минимум идентификатор пользователя - `user_id`. Есть таблица сообщений, которая хранит некоторый уникальный идентификатор, идентификатор диалога и само сообщение, возможно, еще и дату. Есть третья таблица в которой мы свяжем для начала пару пользователей, отправителя и получателя, а так же их идентификатор диалога. Получим:

> Users -- user_id:PK:autoincr|blabla
>
> Messages -- message_id:PK:autoinkr|dialog_id|message_text|datetime
>
> Users2Messages -- dialog_id:PK:autoinkr|sender_user_id|receiver_user_id -- и все это вместе должно быть уникальным

При добавлении сообщения, вы его помещаете в соответствующую таблицу, используя для поля `dialog_id` полученное или сгенерированное значение одноименного поля из таблицы `Users2Messages`. При просмотре вы сможете показывать сразу все сообщения между этими двумя пользователями (проверяя `dialog_id` и принадлежность пользователей к данному кортежу). Можно расширить до "много пользователей пишут многим пользователям одно сообщение". Навеяно ВК.

**Второй вариант** описал [@FLK](/users/6551/flk) (решение похоже на мой вариант), т.е. ваша задача для двух пользователей, а может и больше, вести идентификатор их сообщений (можно добавить еще направление) начиная с 0 для каждого нового вхождения `sender|receiver`. Причем не забывайте сделать необходимые подмножества полей уникальными.

Comment: Чудеса какие-то, сам не понял че я сделал, но id сообщения ставится как надо. Собственно сделал как написано ниже "в базе сделайте поле ИД не уникальным, а уникальным связку ид+юзер_ид", сначала не работало, тогда очистил таблицу с помощью EMPTY, id стали присваиваться как положено (всё в одной таблице). http://s019.radikal.ru/i644/1203/d9/919357e978cd.png

Comment: @xenon, это самый простейший вариант, не знаю, кто @lnart поставил минус.

Comment: мда, способ @Inart не совсем корректен, если я пишу сообщение пользователю, то оно считается моим, присваивается к моему id а не к id получателя... а по поводу вашего способа вопрос, то есть dialog_id:PK:autoinkr|sender_user_id|receiver_user_id все эти поля выделяем и жмем unique я так понял?

Comment: @xenon, достаточно сделать уникальными только поля идентификаторов пользователей. И странно, что вы больше склонились к моему варианту, вариант @FLK более прост в реализации, а мой далеко не идеален, т.е. вам придется дорабатывать и кое-что, возможно, править.

Comment: если честно, возникла проблема в варианте FLK не могу понять в чем, сделал поле ИД не уникальным, а уникальным связку ид+юзер_ид, запутался окончательно с PK кому присваивать кому нет, в итоге сейчас при добавлении сообщения id становится 0 (если PK на нём отключен), а если поставить на id PK, то опять идет нумерация по порядку для всех пользователей... не думал что застряну на такой казалось бы простой задаче

Answer (score 2):

структура таблицы должна быть следующая id(auto_increment), sender_id, receiver_id, message
когда пользователь авторизован получаем его личный id (сессии, кукис кому как удобно) таким образом выборка будет осуществляться следующим образом:

```
select * from table where receiver_id='1' and id='123'
```

получаем все сообщения полученные этим пользователем. где 1 это id текущего пользователя, а 123 id сообщения

**Дополнено:**

вариант со связкой. две таблицы. первая где хранятся сообщения:
id(auto_increment), message
вторая таблица для связки:
id(auto_increment),sender_id,reciever_id,message_id,custom_message_id
здесь custom_message_id то самое ваше поле, которое должно быть неуникальным. принцип добавления следующий:

```
 1. добавляем текст сообщения в первую таблицу, получаем его id
 2. вычисляем следующее значение для custom_message_id (выборка с учетом пользователя пославшего сообщение), увеличиваем на единицу
 3. добавляем строки в связку(вторую таблицу) задаем нужный custom_message_id
```

Comment: Одно только забыли, если сообщение может быть отправлено сразу нескольким пользователям, придется для каждого копировать сообщение. Поэтому лучше использовать таблицу-связку, а сообщения не будут иметь ссылок на пользователей.

**Стиль**

Для именования полей (как в общем-то и при документировании) необходимо придерживаться одного стиля. В данном контексте слово `target` не совсем согласуется с `sender`, поэтому я бы рекомендовал `receiver`. Аналогично, как не комильфо, например, называть одного источником (`source`), а второго получателем (`receiver`), когда нужно назначение (`destination`).

Comment: @Dex согласен, исправил. связка, по поводу сообщения многим в вопросе ни слова, но вы правы лучше сразу учитывать подобное нежели потом переписывать по новой.

Comment: у меня получается итак такая структура: user_id, send_id, message, message_id(auto_increment), выборка: SELECT * FROM message WHERE send_id = (куки) ORDER BY message_id DESC, тем не менее у каждого пользователя разные id сообщений и нет повторяющихся....
про таблицу связку подробней можно?

Comment: Вы храните в таблице связке следующие данные:

> ID - autoincrement, PK - уникальный ключ
> Sender_ID - отправитель сообщения
> Receiver_ID - получатель сообщения
> Message_ID - идентификатор сообщения

В таблице сообщений, у вас остаются только Message_ID и MessageText

В таблицу сообщений вы добавляете только сообщение, а в таблицу-связку добавляете отправителя и всех получаетелей + Message_ID добавленного сообщения.

Comment: @xenon, не могу не заметить, что вы немного запутались в том, что вам нужно. Попробуйте переформулировать задание как можно четче, здесь в комментариях. Старайтесь только описать как можно проще, возможно по шагам и с примером.

Comment: Ну вот рассмотрю на примере Вк. Есть страница сообщений пользователя /mail на ней только часть сообщения, остальная часть сообщения появится при переходе по ссылке /mail?act=show&id=15614, 15614 - это id сообщения для конкретного пользователя (в данном случае для меня), то есть всего у меня 15614 сообщений (включая входящие и исходящие), если я перейду по /mail?act=show&id=1, то мне покажет мое первое сообщение (отправленное или полученное), если другой пользователь у себя на странице перейдет по /mail?act=show&id=1, то ему покажет уже ЕГО первое сообщение. Как-то так.

Comment: @Dex ему нужно чтобы в адресной строке не было больших чисел, т.е. чтобы для идентификации сообщения не использовался id из таблицы с сообщениями. а было указан номер сообщения отправленного каким либо пользователем. т.е. если к примеру пользователь отправил 100 сообщений то в адресной строке доступ к 100-му сообщению был ?message=100 как то так, надеюсь не запутал еще больше )

Comment: да да) именно это мне и надо)

Comment: @xenon дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

ну так в базе сделайте поле ИД не уникальным, а уникальным связку  ид+юзер_ид  и все